# AJAX enabled web form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am new to Jquery and want some help from you guys.

i want to decode json data in jquery as i am able to pass data from php to ajax but after it came back in jquery it is not parsing it says undefined. the code is bellow

### JavaSript file

```
$.post("GetData.php", function(data) {
        if(data==false)
            var tpl = '<p>no record found<p>'
        else
            var tpl = DrawTableRowsforSection(data);
            $("#result").append($(tpl));
},"json");


function DrawTableRowsforSection(p)
{
    alert(p.id[0]);
    var o = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
        alert(p.id[i]);
        o += '<tr><td>'+p.id[i]+'</td><td>'+p.section_name[i]+'<td></tr>';

        o+='</table>'
        return O;
}
```

### PHP Script

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') ;
mysql_select_db('news');
session_start();

$query = 'select id,section_name from section';

if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    if (!mysql_num_rows($result)==null) {
        $myArray = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id =  ToSring($row['id']);
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($myArray);
    }
}
```

The database has a table named section
fields are as follows

```
id            int(11)
section_name  varchar(20)
```

There are total 5 records there.

What I want is to populate a table using returned data.
Can any one guide me where I am making mistake

Regards
Kashif Afzaal

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that mysql returns results and you can take them through ajax.

Also, I've seen the following mistake:

You are using the variable `tpl` wrong. It is just a js variable, no need to use $ .
Use this way:

```
 $("#result").append(tpl);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, from the top in the PHP script:

- The MySQL extension is ancient and decrepit. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
- You never handle a failed MySQL query, so the response will quite possibly be empty. In 99% of cases, any `if` block should have a corresponding `else` block.
- The result of `mysql_num_rows()` is *never* `null`. Do `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`, or better yet, just `if (mysql_num_rows($result))`.
- Never do `if (!something == something)` - it rarely does what you want it to. Do `if (something != something)`
- You never handle `mysql_num_rows()` failing/giving no rows, so (again) the response will quite possibly be empty.
- You never do anything with the `$id` variable you create.
- I'm pretty sure `ToSring` should read `ToString`. But there's actually no such function in PHP - you would have either define it or invoke it as a method of a class/object. Indeed, this is likely to be the problem, as it will result in a fatal error.